# Significance test for AB testing of email marketing campaign - data in MySQL

Tags: sql, excel, ab-testing

I have 50,000 email ids divided into Group A and Group B equally.
An email is sent to both groups with different subject.
The Open Rate is as follows:

```
Group | Emails_Opened | Total Emails | Open Rate
A     |  24332        |  34471       | 70.5869% 
B     |  24020        |  33761       | 71.1427%
```

Which significance test should I run to make sure the results are statistically significant and how?
The data is in SQL database.

Comment: I would do it in Excel and use Chisq.test. You would need to add another column, Emails_Unopened, and also work out the expected values from the marginal totals.

Comment: I understand Emails_Unopened. What do you mean by expected values from the marginal totals and how do i find this?

Comment: It's not difficult but it's probably easier just to show you

Answer (score 1):

So you fill in the column totals and row totals, then each expected value is

```
<corresponding column total>*<corresponding row total>/<grand total>
```

e.g.

```
=B$4*$D2/$D$4
```

[image]

Then use

```
=CHISQ.TEST(B2:C3,F2:G3)
```